# Web app manifest orientation property: What is the difference between its properties?

Tags: web, wpa, web-manifest

What is the difference between "any" and "natural" ?
What is the difference between "landscape", "landscape-primary" and "landscape-secondary" ?
What is the difference between "portrait", "portrait-primary" and "portrait-secondary" ?

Comment: All of them are explained in the API spec: https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#screen-orientation-types-and-locks

Comment: @sinanspd Thank you, you can post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Directly taking the definitions from the [API Spec](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#screen-orientation-types-and-locks):

**Landscape-primary** is an orientation where the screen width is greater than the screen height. If the device's natural orientation is landscape, then it is in landscape-primary when held in that position. If the device's natural orientation is portrait, the user agent sets landscape-primary from the two options as shown in the screen orientation values table.

**Landscape-secondary** is an orientation where the screen width is greater than the screen height. If the device's natural orientation is landscape, it is in landscape-secondary when rotated 180º from its natural orientation. If the device's natural orientation is portrait, the user agent sets landscape-secondary from the two options as shown in the screen orientation values table.

**Portrait-primary** is an orientation where the screen width is less than or equal to the screen height. If the device's natural orientation is portrait, then it is in portrait-primary when held in that position. If the device's natural orientation is landscape, the user agent sets portrait-primary from the two options as shown in the screen orientation values table.

**Portrait-secondary** is an orientation where the screen width is less than or equal to the screen height. If the device's natural orientation is portrait, then it is in portrait-secondary when rotated 180º from its natural position. If the device's natural orientation is landscape, the user agent sets portrait-secondary from the two options as shown in the screen orientation values table.

**Portrait** is an orientation where the screen width is less than or equal to the screen height and depending on platform convention locking the screen to portrait can represent portrait-primary, portrait-secondary or both.

**Landscape** is an orientation where the screen width is greater than the screen height and depending on platform convention locking the screen to landscape can represent landscape-primary, landscape-secondary or both.

**Natural** is an orientation that refers to either portrait-primary or landscape-primary depending on the device's usual orientation. This orientation is usually provided by the underlying operating system.

**Any** is an orientation that means the screen can be locked to any one of portrait-primary, portrait-secondary, landscape-primary and landscape-secondary.

Comment: **Primary:** expected orientation for portrait/landscape (portrait -> upright)
**Secondary:** not expected orientation (180º upside-down)
**Without Primary/Secondary:** Both is possible