# Progressive web app stuck in portrait mode despite auto-rotate being enabled on phone

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, autorotate

I'm developing a website which I've also created a Progressive Web App (PWA) Android app for by using https://pwabuilder.com

In my `manifest.json` file I initially had the `orientation` property set to `any`, but with this, the installed PWA on my phone would auto-rotate, despite "Auto Rotate" being disabled on my phone. No good.

[Description of manifest.json property values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522804)

So I tried setting the `orientation` property in my `manifest.json` to `natural` instead, and I also tried just deleting the property entirely, but in both cases now *all* rotation was disabled. That is, regardless of whether or not I enable or disable "Auto Rotate" on my phone, the installed app is stuck in portrait mode.

None of this is a problem on the website version of the site of course. If I just navigate to the page in Chrome, it works fine. That is, if I disable "Auto Rotate" on my phone, then the site doesn't rotate, but if I enable it, then it rotates when I physically rotate my phone. I just want my PWA to mimic this behavior, but I'm not exactly sure how.

What value should I be setting the `orientation` property to in my `manifest.json` in order to mimic the default behavior of the website?